# Filtering XElements by descendent element's attributes

Tags: .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to select elements based on the attributes of sub a element of that element.

Original Xml:

```
<Root>
      <Element1 id="1">
        <element2>XXXX</element2>
        <element3>XXXX</element3>
        <element4>XXXX</element4>
        <Filter attr1="1" attr2="0" attr3="0" attr4="1" attr5="0"></Filter>
      </Element1>
      <Element1 id="2">
        <element2>XXXX</element2>
        <element3>XXXX</element3>
        <element4>XXXX</element4>
        <Filter attr1="1" attr2="0" attr3="1" attr4="1" attr5="0"></Filter>
      </Element1>
      <Element1 id="3">
        <element2>XXXX</element2>
        <element3>XXXX</element3>
        <element4>XXXX</element4>
        <Filter attr1="1" attr2="1" attr3="0" attr4="1" attr5="0"></Filter>
      </Element1>
    </Root>
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
Dim xmlElement = (From rec In RecipeXmlDocument.Descendants("Element1") _
Where (rec.Descendants("Filter").@attr1= "1" _
                   Or rec.Descendants("Filter").@attr2 = "0" _
                   Or rec.Descendants("Filter").@attr3 = "0" _
                   And (rec.Descendants("Filter").@attr4 = "1" _
                        Or rec.Descendants("Filter").@attr5 = "0" _
```

This throws the following error: "Exception of type 'System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugViewEmptyException' was thrown."

What the code is trying to do is to select all the Element1s where the filter element of that element1 matches the where clause of the statement.

I'm fairly new to linq and i'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case where it's likely that XPath will produce the right result with less work than it would take to do with LINQ.  You can formulate an XPath query like:

```
/Root/Element1[Filter[(@attr1 = '1' or @attr2 = '0' or @attr3 = '0')
                  and (@attr4 = '1' or @attr5 = '0')]]
```

(I added parentheses around the tests conjoined with `or` because I suspect that's what you want, but I could be wrong.)  That will find all `Element1` elements that have a `Filter` child element whose attributes pass the predicate described.

Then you can just iterate over those elements by using `XDocument.XPathSelectElements()`:

```
var elements = doc.XPathSelectElements(xpath);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be going into this direction:

```
RecipeXmlDocument.Root.Elements()
.Where(e => e.Elements("Filter").SingleOrDefault( [filter conditions] ) != null);
```

This takes all elements under root where a single sub element named "Filter" matches the [filter conditions]. If no such sub element exists the `SingleOfDefault` will return `null` and therefore the `Where` clause is false and the element is not included.

You'll probably have to fine-tune this a little according to your case.

[filter conditions] could be something like:

```
f => f.Attribute("attr1").Value == "1" && f.Attribute("attr2").Value == "2"
```

**UPDATE: My attempt to convert it to VB.net (fingers crossed):**

```
Dim xmlElement = 
 (From rec In RecipeXmlDocument.Descendants("Element1") _
 Where not (From filter in rec.Elements("Filter").Any( _
 Function(f) f.Attribute("attr1") = "1" And f.Attribute("attr2") = "2") is Nothing)
```

Highly likely this will not compile and you need to make adjustments but I hope it helps :)

Comment: Instead of `SingleOrDefault` you want something like `Any` because its name actually says what it's intended to do here.

Comment: This seems promising, but I'm struggling to convert the statement to vb.net.

Comment: @Martinffx, yes I was afraid of that, it's C# and your code is VB, hence my mentioning of the "fine-tuning". I don't know VB nor the expression syntax of Linq well enough to convert it. I hoped VB has a method syntax as well and you could somehow infer what I meant. Unfortunately not. I'll give it a shot see if it helps.